# Need help using Jsoup in Android Studio

Tags: java, html, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup

I need some help getting the text from tags labeled "a". I've looked at a couple of tutorials and I am just not sure what I am doing wrong.

Java:

```
`public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        ArrayList<String> dayMenu;
        String words;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("Cant Post URL For Reasons").get();
                dayMenu = new ArrayList<String>();
                //String monday26 = "ul.vertical.medium-horizontal.menu.item.drilldown ul";
                String str = "#MainContent_RptMenuCalendar_RptMenuItems_0_LbtnMenuItems_0 vertical.medium-horizontal.menu.item.drilldown a";
                String str1 = "div.is-drilldown a";
                String mon26 = "a.MainContent_RptMenuCalendar_RptMenuItems_0_LbtnMenuItems_0 a";
                System.out.println(words);
                String str2 = "div.is-drilldown a";
                int i =0;
                Elements temp = doc.select("ul.vertical.medium-horizontal.menu.item.drilldown");
                for (Element menuItems : temp) {
                    i++;
                    //System.out.println(i + " " + menuItems.getElementsByTag("a").first().text());
                    dayMenu.add(menuItems.getElementsByTag("li").first().text().toString());
                }
                words = String.valueOf(i);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return null;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //if ((dayMenu.get(0).length()) > 2)
                //System.out.println(words);
            //else
                for (int i = 0; i < dayMenu.size(); i++){
                    System.out.println(dayMenu.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println(words);

        }
    }`
```

Html:[(The Html) I highlighted the portion I am trying to extract.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GRRK.png)

Comment: Print `doc` and see if searched element is there (sometimes some elements are added by browser dynamically - via JavaScript -  but Jsoup doesn't support JS so it is parsing *original/initial* version of HTML which may not contain elements you are looking for).

Comment: I think you might just be right. Do you happen to know if there is a way to work around that?

Comment: For Android unfortunately no, but I am not Android dev so it doesn't mean there are no solutions for that. But outside of Android solution is to not use Jsoup but some other tool which supports JS, like Selenium webdriver (but again, Android may have its own better way to generate HTML with dynamic elements - if I recall correctly some people ware trying to use WebView for that, but I am not sure if they succeed).

Comment: I guess that's the next move. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am also ***not an Android guy***.  I think you load the **URL** with `class WebView`, and then retrieve the _"post-script-processed"_ **HTML** from `WebView`, and afterwards you can parse that **HTML** `String` using **JSoup** (or any **HTML Parser**).

Comment: Pls copy/paste the HTML rather than sharing a screen shot and you can be helped

Comment: [`Optical Character Recognition`](https://stackoverflowanswer.blogspot.com/2020/11/optical-character-recognition.html) provided by [`Google Cloud Server`](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Elements temp = doc.select("ul.vertical.medium-horizontal.menu.item.drilldown");
```

is not going to work. The class is one string not multiple that you can drill-down into one level at a time... which is what this would effectively do. See https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation for info on the selector syntax.

Instead try the below and you may have more luck:

```
Elements temp = doc.select("ul[@class='vertical medium-horizontal menu item drilldown'] li a");
for (Element ahref : temp){
    System.out.println(ahref.text());
}
```